# Using other Google API's in a Google cloud endpoints project (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-endpoints, google-contacts-api

I'm using a Google Cloud Backends Project in Python to support an Android App. I want the server to be able to make some API calls on the user's accounts
(like Contacts, Maps, etc) rather than have the Android client take this overhead.
**I am not using Webapp at all**. I'd prefer not to - I don't see the need per se, unless it is the only way to make this work.

Wondering how I'd go forward:

```
@endpoints.api(name='data_api',
           version='v1',
           description='Access, create or delete data for meetups.',
           audiences=client_ids.allowed_client_ids,
           scopes=[  # Get email and Details
                     endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE,
                     # Get Contacts
                     client_ids.CONTACTS_SCOPE
           ])
class DataApi(remote.Service):
@UserModel.method(name='user.fetch',
                  user_required=True)
def get_all_contacts(self, query):
    #Now what?
```

I suppose need to relay the Auth token onto another custom request from the server to Google API's, but I don't know how to extract it and push it forward. Couldn't find it in the documentation or any questions here.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I do know how to check if a user is authenticated, but that doesn't tell me how to hit the Google API's with the same auth token.

```
if endpoints.get_current_user() is not None:
    #Do secret authenticated business...
```

Answer (score 1):

The final step of the OAuth2 flow, the retrieved token sits in the API request headers. We can access it so:

```
import os
self.bearer = os.getenv('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```

This provides the bearer string that can be relayed to hit other APIs. With the right scopes, when done using the atom and gdata Python libraries, we need to dress this up in a new object found here: https://github.com/ca9/meetup-backend/blob/master/atom/auth.py

in the EndpointsAuth class.

Use with gdata as follows:

```
if e_user:
        gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='<var>intense-terra-821</var>', auth_token=EndpointsAuth())
```

under any endpoint function.